# Не работает клик по кнопке JS

Tags: javascript, html

На HTML странице есть две кнопки с одним и тем же классом "BACK". И есть JS код который должен выполняться при нажатии на эти кнопки в зависимости от условия

```
var discription = document.querySelector('#menu-discription');
var priceList = document.querySelector(".priceList");
var contacts = document.querySelector('.contacts');
document.querySelector(".back").onclick = function(){
        if (priceList.style.marginLeft = '0px') {
            priceList.style.marginLeft = '-3000px';
            discription.style.marginLeft = '5%';
        }
        if (contacts.style.marginLeft = '0px') {
            contacts.style.marginLeft = '-3000px';
            discription.style.marginLeft = '5%';
        }
    }
```

При нажатии на первую кнопку (она и первая на странице идет) всё работает, всё двигается, а при нажатии на эту кнопку но уже в другом блоке .contacts  - не видит клика. В консоли ошибок никаких нет. Я уже думал может эту функцию нельзя подвязывать к двум разным кнопкам и оно срабатывает тоолько на той что идет раньше на странице, но поменяв сами кнопки местами всё равно в .priceList работает ав .contacts нет. Так же менял местами условия if, такой же результат  в .priceList работает ав .contacts нет.

Суть задачи: есть несколько блоков которые могут поочередно выезжать из-за края экрана, и в каждом таком блоке есть кнопка "назад" - спрятать этот блок обратно за экран

Comment: Советую прочитать [«Поиск: getElement*, querySelector*»](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom) и [«Стили и классы»](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes) | И ещё вот это [«Консоль разработчика»](https://learn.javascript.ru/devtools)

Answer (score 1):

document.querySelector('.back') найдет первый попавшийся и навесит событие на него. Вам нужен querySelectorAll который выберет все .back и в цикле на них навесить onclick

Comment: понял следующим образом:
document.querySelectorAll(".back").onclick = function(){
   if (priceList.style.marginLeft = '0px') {
    priceList.style.marginLeft = '-3000px';
    discription.style.marginLeft = '5%';
   }
   if (contacts.style.marginLeft = '0px') {
    contacts.style.marginLeft = '-3000px';
    discription.style.marginLeft = '5%';
   }
  }

теперь вообще БЭК не работает нигде

Comment: нет, backList =  document.querySelectorAll(".back"); backList.forEach(function(backItem) { backItem.onclick = ваша функция });

Comment: сорян, но не работает, выдает ошибку TypeError: priceList is undefined

Comment: Я не пытался написать код за вас, я указал вам вектор в котором этот код заработает, ваш код не может работать по определению, вы написали 2 if подряд в нем же в условии установили для блока отступ вместо того чтобы сравнить.... И очень еще много ошибок точнее необдуманных действий